# Solution for C# occurence but not using LINQ

Tags: c#, find-occurrences

> For a given string in C# count the number of occurrences of each >character that repeats itself (occurs more than once).

**Example:**

```
string str = "abcdzefazz";
```

**Expected output:**

```
Character a has 2 occurrences. 
Character z has 3 occurrences.
```

Comment: `"Some string".GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() >1).ToDictionary(x => x, x => x.Count())` note, its late in the day, this could be completely wrong.

Comment: Off Topic, @WaiHaLee how on earth did you get so many gold badges for that rep? :)

Comment: @TheGeneral https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward?userid=1364007

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto oh I see, thanks... Well, that's a lot of reviews, I barely can do 10 before I get bored

Answer (score 1):

Well, for *No Linq solution* you can use good old `foreach` loop with a help of *dictionary* `Dictionary<char, int>`. Here `Key` is character itself and `Value` is occurence:

```
  string str = "abcdzefazz";

  ...

  Dictionary<char, int> occurence = new Dictionary<char, int>();

  foreach (char c in str)
    if (occurence.TryGetValue(c, out value))
      occurence[c] = value + 1;
    else
      occurence.Add(c, 1);
```

When you want to know occurence (`number`) of `ch` character:

```
  char ch = 'z';

  ...

  int number = occurence.TryGetValue(ch, out value) ? value : 0;
```

To print *all* `occurence`, just loop over the dictionary:

```
  foreach (var pair in occurence)
    Console.WriteLine($"Character {pair.Key} has {pair.Value} occurrences");
```

To obtain all characters with more then 1 ocurrence, just add condition:

```
  foreach (var pair in occurence)
    if (pair.Value > 1)
      Console.WriteLine($"Character {pair.Key} has {pair.Value} occurrences");
```